# Mongoose error: "Topology was destroyed", what's the problem?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I was coding a leveling system for my discord bot, but encountered a mongoerror on the way, does anyone know why this is occuring? (The addXp function runs whenever someone chatted, the error is logged in the removeTimeout function.) I have used mongoose in many more ways in my code but this hasn't yet occured before, I also did find others' issues with this error but found no fitting solution there.

```js
async function removeTimeout(leveldataid) {
    console.log("removetimeout")
    await mongo().then(async (mongoose) => {
        try {
            await levelSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(
                leveldataid,
                {
                    _id: leveldataid,
                    oncooldown: false
                },
                {upsert: true}
            )
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
        } finally {
            mongoose.connection.close()
        }
    })


}

async function addXP(member, guild) {
    let data = undefined
    let changedleveldata = false
    await mongo().then(async (mongoose) => {
        try {
            data = await levelenabledSchema.findById(guild.id)
            if (data) {
                if (data.enabled == true) {
                    let extraxp = Math.floor(Math.random() *20) + 15
                    let leveldata = await levelSchema.findById(`guild${guild.id}member${member.id}`)
                    if (!leveldata) {
                        await levelSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(
                            `guild${guild.id}member${member.id}`,
                            {
                                _id: `guild${guild.id}member${member.id}`,
                                guild: guild.id,
                                level: 1,
                                maxXp: 113,
                                xp: extraxp,
                                oncooldown: true
                            },
                            {upsert: true}
                        )
                    } else {
                        if (leveldata.oncooldown == false) {
                            let newlevel = leveldata.level
                            let newMaxXp = leveldata.maxXp
                            newMaxXp = Math.floor(newMaxXp)
                            let xp = leveldata.xp

                            xp +=extraxp

                            if (xp > leveldata.maxXp) {
                                xp -=Math.floor(100*1.135**newlevel)
                                newlevel++
                                newMaxXp = 100*1.13**newlevel
                            }
                            await levelSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(
                                `guild${guild.id}member${member.id}`,
                                {
                                    level: newlevel,
                                    maxXp: newMaxXp,
                                    xp: xp,
                                    oncooldown: true
                                },
                                {upsert: true}
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            changedleveldata = true
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
        } finally {
            mongoose.connection.close()
        }
        if (changedleveldata == true) {
            setTimeout(remoteTimeout(`guild${guild.id}member${member.id}`), 60000)
        }
    })

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This basically means the connection between node server and mongoDB was interrupted while writing data.

The solution to your problem would be to remove the `finally` block from your code because it interrupts the connection when the bot is being used by a lot of users and the bot tries to write data while a previous connection is being closed.

```js
await mongo().then(async (mongoose) => {
    try { // code here 
    } catch(e) { console.log(e); } 
});
```

Comment: I did this, and didn't work, with your explanation I went through my script though, and found out I closed the connection in a different function that also ran at every message sent! Thanks for letting me know why this happens!

Comment: np happy to help :D